# Plot scatter data and create a heatmap using Python

Tags: python, heatmap, scatter-plot

I showed an image to consumers and asked them to click on a point they liked most. So, I got clicks data (x,y format where x goes from left to right and y goes from bottom to top) on that image. I am trying to create a heatmap using the same and overlay it on the original image.

**my code**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import imageio.v2 as imageio
import cv2
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter

image_path = 'C:\\Users\\Anurag\\Desktop\\Heatmaps\\Original design\\Holi control_withPrice1.png'
image = imageio.imread(image_path)

clicks_file = 'C:\\Users\\Anurag\\Desktop\\Heatmaps\\clickfiles\\Study1_Q19_1stArea.csv'
clicks_data = pd.read_csv(clicks_file)

x = clicks_data['x'].values
y = clicks_data['y'].values

marker_size = 40
extent = [0, image.shape[1], 0, image.shape[0]]
plt.clf()
plt.scatter(x, y, c='red', s=marker_size,alpha=0.5,cmap='jet') 
plt.imshow(image, extent=extent, origin='upper', alpha=0.3)
plt.show()

heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x,y,bins=(image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))
heatmap = gaussian_filter(heatmap, sigma=16)
extent = [0, image.shape[1], 0,image.shape[0]]  # Set extent to match image size

plt.clf()
plt.imshow(image, extent=extent, origin='upper', alpha=0.3)
plt.imshow(heatmap.T, extent=extent, origin='lower', alpha=.5,cmap='jet')
plt.show()
```

**Outputs I am getting**

Scatter plot I am getting:

[image: Scatter plot I am getting]

Heatmap I am getting:

[image: Heatmap I am getting]

**Problems I need help in resolving**

1. If you look at the scatter plot and heatmap above, you would that My heatmap and scatter plot points seem different and are not exactly in the same places.
2. Intensity of the heatmap is low. I need it to appear something like below (Just a sample).

Expected result with image overlay:

[image: expected result with image overlay]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This should be two questions. Problems 1. and 2. are completely unrelated.

Comment: You need to pass the range parameter to `np.histogram2d`. You don't tell numpy the size of the image, so it cannot know. See the docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html

Comment: The matplotlib docs have great descriptions on how to use and modify colormaps. You might wanna try a logarithmic colormap: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormapnorms.html#logarithmic

Answer (score 0):

The example below overlays an alpha-shaded density map onto scatter data, with an image underneath. It's a modification of your original code.

Decreasing `bw_method=` will make the density map more clustered, and increasing it will make it more spread out.

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image

image_path = 'img.png'
image = np.array( Image.open(image_path) )

# 
# Create test data
#
# clicks_data = pd.read_csv(clicks_file)
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
X, _ = make_blobs(n_samples=300, centers=4, random_state=3)
X -= X.min(axis=0)
X = (X * 20).round().astype(int)
clicks_data = pd.DataFrame({'x': X[:, 0], 'y': X[:, 1]})

#
# Scatter data and render image
#
x = clicks_data['x'].values
y = clicks_data['y'].values

adjust_scale = 1 #adjust scale if required, respecting image proportions
extent = [0, x.max() * adjust_scale, 0, image.shape[0] / image.shape[1] * x.max() * adjust_scale]
plt.scatter(x, y, c='tab:brown', s=10, alpha=.8, edgecolor='none', marker='s')
plt.imshow(image, extent=extent, alpha=0.3, origin='upper')

#
#Fit a density estimator
#
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
density_estimator = gaussian_kde(dataset=clicks_data.values.T, bw_method=0.2)

#Get the density estimates over a fine grid
grid_resolution = 100
x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(0, extent[1], num=grid_resolution),
    np.linspace(0, extent[3], num=grid_resolution)
)
grid_coords = np.column_stack([x_grid.ravel(), y_grid.ravel()])
density_map = density_estimator(grid_coords.T).T.reshape(x_grid.shape)

#Modify the cmap to have alpha shading from transparent to opaque
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

cmap_name = 'jet'
cmap_rgba = plt.get_cmap(cmap_name)(range(256))
cmap_rgba[:, -1] = np.linspace(0, 1, len(cmap_rgba))
cmap_alpha = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(name='', colors=cmap_rgba)

plt.imshow(
    density_map, extent=extent, interpolation='spline16',
    origin='lower', cmap=cmap_alpha
)

#Optional formatting
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(4, 4)
plt.gca().axis('off')
plt.show()
```